# Spray with Air Timeout for Comet

Tags: air, comet, akka, long-polling, spray

I am building an Air application that long-polls a Spray server to get relevant updates.

I am new to Spray and have read that, if requests are not handled on time, a 500 timeout error is automatically sent to the client by the framework. I can catch this error on the Air side, and then send another request, etc.

Are there any drawbacks to using this approach (I cannot think of any) or is it better to avoid the timeout and send back some sort of "no news" message to the client instead?

Answer (score 0):

I would say, from a RESTful perspective, that the response should pertain to the state of the resource. Looking at the available response codes:

> **204 No Content** The server successfully processed the request, but is
>   not returning any content.

This states that the request was carried out successfully yet there is nothing to return.

[204 No Content](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.2.5)